# When it is OK to use SELECT * in SQL

Tags: sql, select

I understand that in general it is a bad idea to use SELECT * in SQL. Are there any exception cases? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you need *every* column, both current and future, taking into account that some may be added or removed.

Usually, this is the case only for tooling that needs database information totally, such as a schema lister, or if you're doing analysis to try and find out where the information that you need actually resides.

It's almost *never* needed for "real" applications, which should only know about, and ask for, what they need.

You don't want your application falling in a screaming heap just because some other user of the database decided they needed forty-two 2GB BLOB columns added to each and every row :-)

Answer (score 0):

Usually it only matters if you're moving obscene amounts of data, because then your throughput gets maxed out.

I use it with frequency, because it makes ALTERing tables painless as far as your application prototyping is concerned.

As far as processing, it doesn't matter - at all, due to the nature of MySQL.

So don't worry.

Comment: Hum... not sure `SELECT *` is a good idea, *especially* when you're altering the table regularly.

Comment: But if you are prototyping your own application, then you will be aware of what fields you are using. For example, in a foreach(), you only using certain fields anyway. I'm not saying all situations warrant SELECT *: I'm saying that many times, it's completely irrelevant.

Comment: It depends on the API available, it can lead to buggy code if you get the column based on their index and not their name. It's bad practice in general (although not as bad as `INSERT`s without column names, of course).

Comment: Bruno, what is an example of when you should get a column by its index?

Comment: Any on the getters in a [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt%28int%29) (see introduction for issues with names). That's for Java, but other APIs in other languages have similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

If the code that uses it is capable of pulling the column names automatically and map all the names subsequently for further use in your application, you can get away with using `SELECT *`.

However, it's usually a bad idea, since it could be tempting to assume the position of the columns you want to retrieve (depending on the DB API that you use, it may be indexed-based rather than name-based). For readability, it's also often better to write down explicitly what you want to retrieve.

There are a few things that could cause problems when using `SELECT *`:

- if the column label isn't clearly defined (e.g. a `SUM(...)` or other operation coming from a view or a CTE),
- if multiple columns in the selection have the same name (e.g. with joins or views/CTEs with `AS` clauses).

Java's [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) says the following about names:

> Values can be retrieved using either the index number of the column or
>   the name of the column. In general, using the column index will be
>   more efficient.
>
> [...]
>
> When a getter method is called with a column name and several columns
>   have the same name, the value of the first matching column will be
>   returned. The column name option is designed to be used when column
>   names are used in the SQL query that generated the result set. For
>   columns that are NOT explicitly named in the query, it is best to use
>   column numbers. If column names are used, the programmer should take
>   care to guarantee that they uniquely refer to the intended columns,
>   which can be assured with the SQL AS clause.

Comment: This seems to be more an example of the tail of bad java programming practice wagging the SQL server dog

Comment: @podiluska, what do you mean? Retrieving a value by its index in the row isn't specific to Java. This was just an example.

Comment: @podiluska, no my argument is don't use `SELECT *` because you don't know what you're getting and programmers may have a good reason to use `result[2]` (e.g. performance in Java, as stated in the doc, or same column names, more so when programmers don't control the table).